# Chunk Templates include using variable

Tags: chunk-templates

I've been trying to get up to speed with Chunk Templates (great framework, BTW). I'm porting a webapp project from Velocity to CT as a POC. Translating the parse directive is causing me troubles. For example, in Velocity, I can pass the name of the file to include in a variable.

```
#parse(${some_variable_name})
```

The closest things in CT I can find is the include directive, but it seems to reference a literal value.

```
{% include some_variable_name %}
```

This looks for a file named `some_variable_name`. Using the name `$some_variable_name` doesn't work either.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic include that you want to do is possible in Chunk -- just use [backticks](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/wiki/index.php?title=Chunk#Backticks_.28dynamic_tags.29).

Try this:

```
{% include `$some_variable_name` %}
```

Backtick evaluation is carried out prior to tag interpolation, so although include is not designed to accept a tag reference directly, this trick offers a clean workaround.